# javascript/jquery find id number within multidimensional json object and use the object that id number is in as an object by itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

Uh hmm how can I word this. Lets start of with an example of my object:

```
"data": {
    "events": [
        {
            "event_id": 12345,
            "event_ts_begin": 1358931738000,
            "event_ts_end": 1358931748000,
            "event_severity": "minor",
            "event_code": 23,
            "event_desc": "Completed",
            "event_type": "normal",
            "event_text": "Completed, blah on blah blah blah..."
        },
        {
            "event_id": 12346,
            "event_ts_begin": 1358931738000,
            "event_ts_end": 1358931748000,
            "event_severity": "minor",
            "event_code": 23,
            "event_desc": "Completed",
            "event_type": "normal",
            "event_text": "Completed, blah on blah blah blah..."
        },
        {
            "event_id": 12347,
            "event_ts_begin": 1358931738000,
            "event_ts_end": 1358931748000,
            "event_severity": "minor",
            "event_code": 23,
            "event_desc": "Completed",
            "event_type": "normal",
            "event_text": "Completed, blah on blah blah blah..."
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want to do is some how find out where `event_id` 12346 is in this multidimensional object and use that particular data set as an object by itself. Somehow taking it out and defining a temporary variable as that object so it would be equal to:

```
var tempObj = {
            "event_id": 12346,
            "event_ts_begin": 1358931738000,
            "event_ts_end": 1358931748000,
            "event_severity": "minor",
            "event_code": 23,
            "event_desc": "Completed",
            "event_type": "normal",
            "event_text": "Completed, blah on blah blah blah..."
        };
```

The sample object above with the multiple objects in it, can be 1,000+ objects or more in some cases. So looping over them and rebuilding an option doesn't sound like a great idea. So I am hoping I can get some feedback to come up with a sane solution.

Is there a way I can find the particular index number of that particular object to use it as a means of defining the temp var?

Comment: Sorry but you must loop :( Check some [phpjs.org](http://phpjs.org/functions/array_intersect/) about arrays to get an optimized code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) function to find elements in array.

```
var tmpObj = $.grep(data.events, function(obj){
    return obj.event_id == '12347'
});
```